# Java : error: cannot find symbol - Websocket

Tags: java, websocket

Hi I tryin to implement websocket server following this snippet :

1. https://gist.github.com/javiergs/362454bd03116108ce03a609b501344d#file-chatserver-java

```
import org.glassfish.tyrus.server.Server;

public class ChatServer {
       public static void main (String[] args) {
    Server server;
    server = new Server ("localhost", 8025, "/folder", ChatServerEndpoint.class);
    try {
      server.start();
      System.out.println("--- server is running");
      while(true){}
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      server.stop();
    }   
  }  
}
```

2. https://github.com/javiergs/Medium/blob/main/Websockets/ChatServerEndpoint.java

When I running the service I got this error :

```
ChatServer.java:7: error: cannot find symbol 
  server = new Server ("localhost", 8025, "/folder", ChatServerEndpoint.class);
```

Does anyone know what's the issue ?

Comment: If `ChatServerEndpoint` is not in the same package as `ChatServer`, you'll have to import that class too.

Comment: Hi @RandyCasburn got it. sorry I'm newbie in java. Thanks buddy

Comment: Hi @RandyCasburn sorry I got new error, could you please to help : ChatServer.java:33: error: no suitable constructor found for Server(String,int,String,Class<ChatServerEndpoint>)
        server = new Server ("localhost", 8025, "/folder", ChatServerEndpoint.class);

Comment: Here is complete one :

Comment: constructor Server.Server(Class<?>...) is not applicable
      (varargs mismatch; String cannot be converted to Class<?>)
    constructor Server.Server(Map<String,Object>,Class<?>...) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to Map<String,Object>)
    constructor Server.Server(String,int,String,Map<String,Object>,Class<?>...) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Class<ChatServerEndpoint> cannot be converted to Map<String,Object>)

Comment: According to the [API documentation for Server](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.glassfish.tyrus/tyrus-server/latest/index.html), you need either a configuration Map or `null` between `"/folder"` and `ChatServerEndpoint.class`

Comment: @RandyCasburn did you mean need to modified like this ? : server = new Server ("localhost", 8025, "/folder", null, ChatServerEndpoint.class);

Comment: Yep. That should work.

Comment: sorry @RandyCasburn got new error : ChatServer.java:18: error: variable log might not have been initialized
    }
    ^

Comment: last error message pointed to last close curly bracket "}" of ChatServer class

Comment: OK - there are some fundamental things you need to learn that will help you understand what happens. I've assisted you with two different questions in this single thread. Stackoverflow prefers that endless support chats like this one, not happen. The reason is because several "new" questions arise - like is happening here. So, ask a new question about the log thing. But, before you do, I recommend you include code in your question that actually has a member variable named "log" within the code someplace (unlike the code above). Good luck to you.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Thanks for your help.